# Sending Documents From a Developer Organization

Tags: apex, api, json, document

I am developing an application in a developer organization which sends emails via POST requests using an external API.

Back in February or so I was able to send Salesforce Documents as attachments in my requests which would arrive at a recipient's inbox as an attachment which was expected. Now however, when I send a Document as an attachment in my requests, the Document/attachment **doesn't reach the recipient's inbox**, even though in Debug logs it shows all of the necessary content.

[image: Email JSON]

I checked the Base64 conversion string and it does convert back into a pdf with the expected content. Another thing that seems odd is the message size itself reflects the size of the attached Document upon arrival even though the attachment is not present. I am at a loss at this point as to what has happened and was wondering if anything has been changed to Developer Organizations that limit this type of functionality or if something else could be wrong. To update my Email Deliverability settings are as follows:

[image: Email Deliverability Settings on Developer Org]

Comment: Did you change the **`Email Deliverability`** settings? Can you **[edit]** your post to add the current configuration of that setting?

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that gmail is stripping the attachments.

Comment: @Adrian Larson I updated the post with my email deliverability settings. I am believe that they are the default settings, but I am not sure as this is the first time I have checked these settings to be honest.